# SSH Command: How to bypass the double quote problem?

Tags: bash, ssh

Suppose I write the following clever `rsh.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git_project=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
git_prefix=`git rev-parse --show-prefix`
name=$(basename '${git_project}')
ssh $1 "cd '${name}' && $2"
```

And in my cli I write:

```
$: rsh.sh vm ls
```

(Any typos aside, suppose it works)

Next, one would want to assume that `rsh.sh` is just like a command prompt, and has full freedom to leverage the double and single quote techniques.

```
# and maybe I'll have to add more escapes
$: rsh.sh vm "cat foo | awk -f '{print(\"bar\")}'"

# but ideally I could skip all that, not parse the cmd string using bash, and write
$: rsh vm cat foo | awk -f '{print("bar")}' 

# however, here, the command will be partitioned by the "|" symbol, and only the 
# first clause is going to be evaluated by the script
```

So, the question is: how does one simply and elegantly (i.e. if a lot of symbolic mangling must occur, then "write a specialized tool to do this" is probably the answer) shim the literal command given at the command line into the spot in the `ssh` command so that everything works just the way a user (me) might expect 3 months from now, for example? (all necessary escape characters accounted for)

---

The complicated solution that I have come up with so far is to solve the simpler problem of grabbing the cli-input data and putting it in a file:

1. Figure out an unknown way to digest the entire contents of the cli string (including pipe characters)
2. Put that content in a shell script in the tmp directory
3. scp that shell script to the remote computer with some hashed name
4. run that shell script with `ssh` rather than try to manage the character escapes

But, ideally, there is some way to nom up the CLI string and plop it into an ssh double quote clause with escape characters evaluated correctly.

Tools that came to mind were `m4`, `tmp` and `sponge`, but I still can't really think of a way to digest the command as a string literal and pop it into the `ssh` command string without engaging `bash` via the `#!/bin/bash` line.

Comment: `project=$(basename '${git_prefix}')`. That's just like writing `project='${git_prefix}'`. There's no `/`, nothing for `basename` to work on.

Comment: @UncleBilly ah, yeah, typo: `project=$(basename '$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)')`

Comment: your question is not clear.anyway. does 4th line works?. and as I understand you should change last line to `ssh $1 "cd '${name}' && ${@:2}"` according your exam ('$: rsh vm cat foo | awk -f '{print("bar")}' 
') but ...

Comment: @HosseinVatani I do not care if my script does not work generally.  It works for the `ls`, and the preamble is to motivate the remainder of the question.

Comment: @HosseinVatani the core question is how does one "pluck" the raw string, as typed in a terminal interface, and "place" that raw string inside the `ssh` quote-string such that all quote escapes are handled properly.  I care about **nothing else** in this question, and everything surrounding that core issue is draft-level sketching and context.

Comment: i guessed it is better to review your question and edit it.

Comment: @HosseinVatani there aren't any tricks here: I am driving right up against the core flaw of bash, and saying: well, "how do we get around this"?  -- And sure, I'll review and edit it when I get another block of time.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, either ;-) Because of the single quotes. Anyways, see my answer; I'm not sure that's what you had in mind.

Comment: You should reconsider the principle of least surprise. Personally, I would hate the person that implemented a command that, when I typed `rsh vm cat foo | something`  gobbled the `|` part to do something other than what the shell normally does. Perhaps you should accept `rsh vm` on its own, then set a special prompt and take the following lines as being specially treated.

Comment: @meuh "hate" -- Anyways, the idea is to have a remote cli interface that looks and acts under my fingers exactly like a local cli...with no transitions; **just** the context prefix.  Super useful to reduce cognitive load and achieve interaction homogeneity.  Two critical features required for that quality that makes a thing "like riding a bike".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what *I think* that is your actual problem (= **get the original command line, unexpanded, and pass it as an argument to another command**), you can use the "alias + comment + history" trick -- which you'll probably find in a lot of answers here and on stackoverflow:

```
alias ush='_ush #'
_ush(){
    local l=$(fc -nl -0)  # get the current command line from history
    l=${l#*ush}           # strip it up to and including the name of the alias (ush)
    l=${l#"${l%%[! ]*}"}  # strip any spaces after the name of the alias
    local h=${l%% *}      # get the user@host part of the command
    l=${l#"$h"}           # get the rest of the command line
    ssh "$h" "$l"         # run the above verbatim on user@host
}

ush user@host echo foo > file
   # will create "file" on the remote host
ush user@host foo | bar
   # will run both foo and bar on the remote host
```

Note: bash will expand aliases after bangs ("history expansions"); short of modifying the bash source code or hooking directly into the readline code, there's no way to get the command line before things like `!!` or `!:$` are expanded. If you're not actively using that (mostly perfunctory) feature, you can safely turn it off with `set +H`.

Comment: this looks like the trick -- thank you.  I'll edit the question when i get the chance